# Cannondale MTB hydraulic brakes

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake

Brake lever pulls straight in to handle bar and brake not working, have tried putting more fluid in but it’s still not working,has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: So what brakes are they? What exactly have you tried already? Are there any leaks? What bleed procedure did you follow?

Comment: It sounds like you have air in the system, I notice you say you have tried more fluid but have you bled the brakes for air bubbles?

Comment: Are you positive you used the correct fluid?   Some brakes use mineral oil, some use DOT fluid like a car.  They must not be mixed.

Comment: I know this seems very obvious but just in case you overlooked it, do your brake pads still have enough material on them?

Answer (score 1):

Your first step is to attempt to bleed the system. The principal that makes hydraulic brakes work is that fluid is not compressible. When the lever is squeezed, fluid is pushed through the hose to the caliper. The displaced fluid needs somewhere to go, so it moves the brake piston towards the rotor activating the brakes. When the lever is released the fluid returns to the brake lever. The piston move away from the rotor and the brakes are released. When air is introduced into the system the fluid doesn't move the piston it compresses the air bubble. This gives you the spongy feeling. The fluid used varies by manufacturer and model. Using an incorrect fluid type can ruin the system. The bleeding method also varies so you need to check with the manufacturer for the correct procedure.